# How to write a generic function that will call a general function with a specific class?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

My code:

```
public class BaseParamsClass
{
    public BaseParamsClass(int pBaseParam = 0)
    {
        baseParam = pBaseParam;
    }

    public int baseParam;
}

public class Parent1ParamsClass : BaseParamsClass
{
    public Parent1ParamsClass(int pBaseParam = 0) : base(pBaseParam)
    {

    }

    public int parentParam1;
}

public class Parent2ParamsClass : BaseParamsClass
{
    public Parent2ParamsClass(int pBaseParam = 0) : base(pBaseParam)
    {

    }

    public int parentParam2;
}

public delegate void Parent1Callback(Parent1ParamsClass theParams);
public delegate void Parent2Callback(Parent2ParamsClass theParams);

private IEnumerator CoRFunction1(Parent1Callback parent1Callback)
{
    // This demonstrate few actions i do before the call
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

    // Now i get the result, it can be 0-10, each one should activate different callback
    int result = 0;

    parent1Callback(new Parent1ParamsClass(0));
}

private IEnumerator CoRFunction2(Parent2Callback parent2Callback)
{
    // This demonstrate few actions i do before the call
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

    // Now i get the result, it can be 0-10, each one should activate different callback
    int result = 0;

    // Need a generic way to do the next line:
    parent2Callback(new Parent2ParamsClass(0));
}

private IEnumerator CoRFunction2(Parent2Callback parent2Callback)
{
    // This demonstrate few actions i do before the call
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

    // Now i get the result, it can be 0-10, each one should activate different callback
    int result = 0;

    // Need a generic way to do the next line:
    parent2Callback(new Parent2ParamsClass(0));
}
```

And what i need is a way to replace the line after the '// Need a...' in something more generic, this is how the last two functions should look like:

```
private IEnumerator CoRFunction1(Parent1Callback parent1Callback)
{
    // This demonstrate few actions i do before the call
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

    // Now i get the result, it can be 0-10, each one should activate different callback
    int result = 0;

    genericFunction<Parent1Callback>(Parent1ParamsClass);
}

private IEnumerator CoRFunction2(Parent2Callback parent2Callback)
{
    // This demonstrate few actions i do before the call
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

    // Now i get the result, it can be 0-10, each one should activate different callback
    int result = 0;

    genericFunction<Parent2Callback>(Parent2ParamsClass);
}
```

Any ideas how to create 'genericFunction'?

Comment: Please strip your example down and create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Could you please describe the thought and aim behind the inheritance approach and the callback call ?=! I have the feeling that you might not need generics here. Do you want to make 1 method from `CoRFunction1` and `CoRFunction2` ?

Comment: @MongZhu, of course. I have 20 coroutines getting data from server, each one need to call a different callback depending on the result. I want to unite them to one coroutine.

Comment: you could do something with Generics here, but it seems a bit clunky.  Can you not just pass the result into the callback function and have that decide what to do?  Then you wouldn't need different callbacks/functions at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I commented - it's not too clear exactly what you're trying to achieve and I suspect you can do this in a better way than what you are trying to... but for the record, I *think* something like the below might work.

Change the base parameter classes so you're not relying on the constructor to set their internal fields, then constrain some generic methods to the base type only, so you'd end up with this sort of thing:

```
public class BaseParamsClass
{
    public virtual void SetParam(int pBaseParam)
    {
        baseParam = 0;
    }

    public int baseParam;
}

public class Parent1ParamsClass : BaseParamsClass
{
    public override void SetParam(int pBaseParam)
    {
        base.SetParam(pBaseParam);
        //do other stuff specific to this class...
    }
    public int parentParam1;
}

public class Parent2ParamsClass : BaseParamsClass
{
    public override void SetParam(int pBaseParam)
    {
        base.SetParam(pBaseParam);
        //do other stuff specific to this class...
    }

    public int parentParam2;
}


public delegate void GenericCallback<T>(T theParams) where T : BaseParamsClass, new();

private IEnumerator GenericCorFunction<T>(GenericCallback<T> callback) where T:BaseParamsClass, new()
{
    // This demonstrate few actions i do before the call
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

    // Now i get the result, it can be 0-10, each one should activate different callback
    int result = 0;

    //I assume you want result here.
    //Also note that you can't use the constructor to set the base param as at compile time
    //we're not sure which type will be being used.  There are ways around this but it's
    //probably clearer to use basic constructor then call the SetParam virtual/overridden method            
    var param = new T();
    param.SetParam(result);
    callback(param);
}
```

you could use it something like this:

```
var newEnumerator = GenericCorFunction<Parent2ParamsClass>(p =>
{
    //this is the callback function body.  This will only run when 
    //called at the end of the GenericCorFunction
    //Do things with p, which will be a PArent2ParamsClass object
    //with its baseParam field set to whatever result was.
    if (p.baseParam == 3)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
});

//do stuff with newEnumerator...
```

Comment: I added an example.  I've used a lambda for the callback function, but this could be a method defined elsewhere....  Still not too sure exactly what you're trying to achieve though - I'd probably simply use a single callback that accepts the result integer and decides what to do....

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be to use [Activator.CreateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d(v=vs.110).aspx). This will allow you to circumvent the `new()` restriction and to use your already written constructor:

```
public delegate void ParentCallback<T>(T theParams) where T : BaseParamsClass;

private void CoRFunction<T>(ParentCallback<T> parentCallback) where T : BaseParamsClass
{    
    // Now i get the result, it can be 0-10, each one should activate different callback
    int result = 0;

    parentCallback((T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), 11));
}
```

(I changed it into void to make it testable for me)

Here is the TestCode and the calls I used to test it:

```
public void Call_1(Parent1ParamsClass par1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("CALL 1 baseParam: " + par1.baseParam);
}

public void Call_2(Parent2ParamsClass par2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("CALL 2 baseParam: " + par2.baseParam);
}
```

Calls:

```
CoRFunction<Parent1ParamsClass>(Call_1);
CoRFunction<Parent2ParamsClass>(Call_2);
```

Output:

> CALL 1 baseParam: 11
>   CALL 2 baseParam: 11